# Multiple groups overlapping - SketchUp Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm probably missing the dangers to this technique since I'm new to the Ruby API (and SketchUp in general), but basically I'm using loops in my project to travel upwards along the z-axis creating individual cylinders stacked one after another.

Now, I'm calling a function (once) which has a for-loop within it that performs this task, but since I need the entire stack to be packed as a single group, I've passed to that function a group initialized within the calling function. Then, the function that generates the stack makes a temporary group and every new cylinder created is made a part of that group. Finally, once the function is finished, it assigns the group it recieved as a parameter to that temporary group.

So, the problem is when I generate the model in SketchUp, and I click on the stack to perform an action on it, like *erase* or *hide*, I have to right click the group and hit the action at least two times before it actually performs it. What is the proper of way of grouping each cylinder so that this doesn't occur?

Here is a sample source code outlining this method: http://codepad.org/E3a1xXVG

Thanks.

UPDATE 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejIuB.png  This screenshot is a frame-by-frame veiw of the problem occuring in the model Sketchup generates from the sample code above. Right clicking the group and selecting an action must be done twice before taking effect. I'm trying to fix the sample code so that an action need only be selected once (as it should behave normally) before I can apply it to my much larger project - which utilizes the same method.

Comment: "I have to right click the group and hit the action at least two times before it actually performs it." Your script creates two cylinders on top of each other. As a result of `group.copy`. Is that something you intended? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Also, why you call the group temporary - no group is erased here.

Comment: Oh... well, of course. How did I miss that? And I call it temporary because if the calling function doesn't pass a 'final' group to it, so if I just keep concatenating entities, it doesn't behave like a group at all. What happens is if I select, say, the middle ring, it only highlights that radial ring and the one(s) below it. I tried exploding the temporary group *after* copying it to the 'final' group, but that caused no grouping to occur once I veiwed the model.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is group the entire tower together, plain and simple. But each time I create the face of the circle, pushpull it, and so on, I'm unsure of how to access that individual entitiy (or is it an array of entities, say a ton of small lines connected and changing in direction by such a small angle to create a smooth circular ring) so that everything can be grouped together.

Comment: After you extruded the face in the group you can traverse the group's entities to find what you are looking for. I'm not entirely sure if I understood what your desired result is. Can you update the question with a screenshot of the desired result?